# No activities found to run, monkey aborted

Tags: android, adb, monkey

Tried to run monkey on my device(xiaomi); getting this error, but other device(samsung) working fine with monkey command.

```
C:\Users\naresh>adb -s <deviceID> shell monkey -p com.an.biometric.sample -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
  bash arg: -p
  bash arg: com.an.biometric.sample
  bash arg: -c
  bash arg: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
  bash arg: 1
args: [-p, com.an.biometric.sample, -c, android.intent.category.LAUNCHER, 1]
 arg: "-p"
 arg: "com.an.biometric.sample"
 arg: "-c"
 arg: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
 arg: "1"
data="com.an.biometric.sample"
data="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
** No activities found to run, monkey aborted.
```

Comment: Is on the other device the exact same app installed you want to start (not just the same package name I really mean the same app installed from the same APK)?

Comment: yeah I checked... thats a bug with my device. Later I rebooted and uninstalled & installed that apk through adb command, it(monkey command) worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

[monkey command working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CUgE.png)

```
whyred:/ $ monkey -p com.an.biometric.sample -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
  bash arg: -p
  bash arg: com.an.biometric.sample
  bash arg: -c
  bash arg: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
  bash arg: 1
args: [-p, com.an.biometric.sample, -c, android.intent.category.LAUNCHER, 1]
 arg: "-p"
 arg: "com.an.biometric.sample"
 arg: "-c"
 arg: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
 arg: "1"
data="com.an.biometric.sample"
data="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
Events injected: 1
## Network stats: elapsed time=54ms (0ms mobile, 0ms wifi, 54ms not connected)
whyred:/ $ exit
```

after uninstalling and installing apk from adb command `adb install xxx.apk`
`adb uninstall xxx.apk` and rebooting, it worked fine.